# Get Player Statistics From XML

Tags: php, xml

I need PHP code which will return an array with the player's stats, from an XML string. I presume Xpath will need to be used.

```
<playerStats>
  <player>
    <blocksDestroyed>1485</blocksDestroyed>
    <blocksPlaced>1882</blocksPlaced>
    <creatureKills>13</creatureKills>
    <currency>0</currency>
    <deaths>7</deaths>
    <isOnline>false</isOnline>
    <itemsDropped>1507</itemsDropped>
    <lastLogin>1312908744</lastLogin>
    <metersTraveled>19236</metersTraveled>
    <playerGroups>Ops</playerGroups>
    <playerKills>0</playerKills>
    <playerName>Joe</playerName>
    <playerSince>1312776719</playerSince>
    <sessionPlaytime></sessionPlaytime>
    <sessionPlaytimeSeconds>-1</sessionPlaytimeSeconds>
    <totalPlaytime>5.16 hours</totalPlaytime>
  </player>
  <player>Another player's stats</player>...
</playerStats>
```

I need to be passed the `<player></player>` node where `<playerName></playerName>` is `$_GET['name']`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php), your XPath query is going to look something like

```
$players = $xml->xpath(
        sprintf('//player[playerName = "%s"]',
                htmlentities($_GET['name'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')
        ));

if (count($players)) {
    $player = $players[0];
}
```